# why is my getY() returning 0?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an ImageView move to the same position of another ImageView via onClickListener() I can return the x but not the y.

the view position I want to copy is in a different layout in the xml one is in a relative layout and the other in linear within the relative.

is it because it checks the y position based on the position from the layout instead of the edge of the screen?

```
public class LevelTwo extends Activity {


ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);




    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    iv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            iv1.setY(iv2.getY());
            iv1.setX(iv2.getX());





        }
    });

}


}
```

the xml layout is something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >





    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wtsa" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"

        />


<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:src="@drawable/wtsblank" 
            />
```

Comment: i think your problem is... in your xml, imageview which have "imageView2" id isn't exist.

Comment: oops sorry that was my bad on the copy and paste I had 3 but was using only 2 for the sake of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it because it checks the y position based on the position from the layout instead of the edge of the screen?

Yes, you're right.

[getY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getY()) returns the visual y position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to the translationY property plus the current top property. And [top](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop()) property is top position of this view relative to its parent.

Comment: ok thanks. so how could I set the Y to the right position? do I set it to the y of the parent layout? and its like the same thing?